# bge python if statements getLinearVelocity

Tags: python, if-statement, blender

Im new to scripting and programming in general, but I have a decent handle on the concepts, however, I need a little help and I am not sure I'm even searching and googling the right terms for what I want to do.
I need help with what I would imagine is a simple if statement in the Blender Game engine 2.71. what I need to do is to get an objects linear velocity in global terms and then check it to see if it is equal to 0 on all vectors, then I wish to add some linear velocity in xyz.

this is what I have but ofcouse it doesnt work: (please dont hate, Im hella-n00b)

```
import bge
from bge import logic

scene = logic.getCurrentScene()

cube = logic.getCurrentController().owner
speed = cube.getLinearVelocity()

if all(speed == 0):
    cube.setLinearVelocity([0, 0, 10], False)
```

Comment: What is `all`? an object, a function or something else?

Comment: You can probably do something like `if tuple(speed)==(0,0,0):` which turns speed into a tuple and then you can just compare all values at once by tuple comparisons.

Comment: Thanks Guys!
tttthomasssss Im a newbie, and all was a float i set up to reference the list :S
@DovGrobgeld THANK YOU! that worked, I need to look up what tuple is, but at any rate that fixed it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only checking for the case when the velocity is zero, you could  use:

```
if sum(speed) == 0:
    cube.setLinearVelocity([0, 0, 10], False)
```

where `sum()` is the built-in python function for summing the values in a `list`.